# Set a font on customised buttons in Android

Tags: android, fonts, android-button

I'm using buttons with a custom background.

First, I've added the button images to the drawable folder.
Then I created a layout for the button in drawable called large_button.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/large_buttom_pressed"
        android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/large_buttom_pressed"
        android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/large_buttom_default" />
</selector>
```

Then I use the button in the activity layout :

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_send"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="test button Text"
    android:onClick="sendMessage"
    android:background="@drawable/large_button"  />
```

The problem is, (aside from the button being taller than I want), that the text in the button is all caps:

[image]

I'd also like to know how I can tell it to use another font (such as the default font, or a font that's already available, not necessarily one I would have to import in a ttf)

I will address the button size problem in another question, so that people who search for one of either issues will not have to read both and possibly become confused.

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at this for the fonts that are either global, or are available as default by google at this link: http://www.google.co.in/design/spec/style/typography.html#typography-typeface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to change the type and style of font from the xml

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:typeface="monospace"/>
```

So that the text will not be all in uppercase

```
android:textAllCaps="false"
```

If you want to change the font from your activity

```
Button btn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.btn);
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Helv Neue 67 Med Cond.ttf");
btn.setTypeface(font);
```

From your activity you can use this

```
private void overrideFonts(final Context context, final View v) {
    try {
        if (v instanceof ViewGroup) {
            ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) v;
            for (int i = 0; i < vg.getChildCount(); i++) {
                View child = vg.getChildAt(i);
                overrideFonts(context, child);
         }
        } else if (v instanceof Button ) {
            ((Button) v).setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "font.ttf"));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
  }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, yes, `android:textAllCaps="false"` does work when I add it to the button in the layout file. Is there a way to do this from the drawable xml file to affect all buttons in the app ?

Comment: Also, same for the font: If I do this in the activity, I will have to write this for every button on every activity in the app. Ideally, I'd only have to write it once.

Answer (score 1):

So to fix the capitalization use:

```
android:textAllCaps="false"
```

To change the font you can use:

```
android:typeface="serif"
```

Default fonts included are: normal, serif, sans, monospace.

Comment: Thank you, yes, `android:textAllCaps="false"` does work when I add it to the button in the layout file. Is there a way to do this from the drawable xml file to affect all buttons in the app ?